# simplifying relations of a group-presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

i'm working on fundamentalgroups and homology of some manifolds.
One of them is the Seifert-Weber-dodecahedral-Space. I computed a presentation for the fundamentalgroup G but i'd like to simplify it or if possible after simplifying it, i'd like to get a "better known" isomorphic group. But I have tried a lot of simplyifing which just didnt give me somthing useful(all on paper).

I know that $G^{abelian}\cong (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^3$ and that G is not finite.

So my questions are: how would one try to work with relations (is there a methodic way)? Does there exist a programm which can work them out for me?

we got 6 generators a,b,c,d,e,f and relations:
$$abcde=1  $$
$$a^{-1}b^{-1}efc=1  $$
$$b^{-1}c^{-1}afd=1  $$
$$c^{-1}d^{-1}bfe=1  $$
$$cfad^{-1}e^{-1}=1  $$

Comment: What is it you are trying to get?

Comment: And you can obviously get one fewer generator **and** one fewer relation by setting $e = (abcd)^{-1}.$

Comment: for example another space i work with is the poincaire-dodecahedral-space, which has a similar set of relations, but if you simplify them in "the proper way", one sees that the group is actually isomorphic to the binary icosahedron-group. somthing along thoughs lines i hope to achive.